# how to add a space between each line in a plot

Tags: r

Let say i have a data like this

```
M<- matrix(rnorm(20),20,5)
x <- as.matrix(sort(runif(20, 5.0, 7.5)))
```

The M has 5 columns with the same values which I want to plot it but I don't want to plot them on each other. I want to show them with a space. What I do is like below

```
plot(x, M[,1], ylim=range(M), ann=FALSE, axes=T,type="l")
Colm <- 2:ncol(M)
lapply(seq_along(Colm),function(i){
  lines(x, M[,i], col=Colm[i])
})
```

Is there any way to make a distance between each line in plot ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a small change to each y value to shift each line slightly.

```
set.seed(595)
M <- matrix(rnorm(20),20,5)
x <- as.matrix(sort(runif(20, 5.0, 7.5)))

plot(NA, ylim=range(M), xlim=range(x), ann=FALSE, axes=T, type="l")

# Amount by which to shift each y value
eps = seq(-0.1, 0.1, length.out=ncol(M))

lapply(1:ncol(M), function(i){
   lines(x, M[,i] + eps[i], col=i)
})
```

[image]

**UPDATE:** In answer to your comment, I think the following is probably what's happening: In your sample code, `x` is a matrix, which behaves essentially the same as a vector when the matrix has only one column. Thus, `x` will return a data vector, so you can just use the object `x` directly in the `lines` function. However, if you're importing `x` as a data frame (for example, using `x=read.table("x.txt", header=TRUE)`, then you need to use `lines(x[,1], M[,i] + eps[i], col=i)` in your code in order to get the vector of data in the first column of the data frame `x`.

Comment: I tried your function on my real data but I got error that x and y are not with the same length , the M ca be find here https://gist.github.com/anonymous/1f401d5c3b88fda66c01d7eabb3c6514 and the x can be find here https://gist.github.com/anonymous/95fff534dbcf2d15d2b7a51fb78b87dd

Comment: Those two data sources have the same number of rows, but check the actual data objects in R to make sure `x` and `M` in your `lines` function really do have the same number of values.

Comment: is there any other way to plot it which I can use for my real data?

Comment: See update to my answer for the likely reason for the error you're getting and what to do about it.

Answer (score 0):

If you use ggplot you can do this easily using the alpha command as indicated in this post:

[Overlapping Lines in ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16874501/overlapping-lines-in-ggplot2)

and you could also jitter the lines using code from this post..

[How to jitter lines in ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29835059/how-to-jitter-lines-in-ggplot2)

Comment: this is not a solution