# ggplot with aes(group = ...) issue

Tags: r, ggplot2

Using my simple data frame

```
> str(dta)
Classes 'tbl_df', 'tbl' and 'data.frame':   54 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ year   : num  2016 2016 2017 2017 2018 ...
 $ severef: num  0.112 0.465 0.11 0.457 0.114 ...
 $ package: Factor w/ 3 levels "Baseline","HSS",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ run_nb : int  1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 ...
```

When running

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dta, aes(x = year, y = severef, color = package, group = run_nb)) +
    geom_line()
```

I am expecting that several distinct lines will be drawn because of the `aes(..., group = run_nb)` as per [Overlapping Lines in ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16874501/overlapping-lines-in-ggplot2)

Instead, the output is jammed. I have tried several transformations of variable types but to no avail. What am I doing wrong?

[image: ggplot output]

```
dta <- structure(list(year = c(2016, 2016, 2017, 2017, 2018, 2018, 2019, 
2019, 2020, 2020, 2021, 2021, 2022, 2022, 2023, 2023, 2024, 2024, 
2016, 2016, 2017, 2017, 2018, 2018, 2019, 2019, 2020, 2020, 2021, 
2021, 2022, 2022, 2023, 2023, 2024, 2024, 2016, 2016, 2017, 2017, 
2018, 2018, 2019, 2019, 2020, 2020, 2021, 2021, 2022, 2022, 2023, 
2023, 2024, 2024), severef = c(0.111823385630219, 0.465018440108279, 
0.109918488465996, 0.457096910073382, 0.11417253918809, 0.474787413895822, 
0.124623038552219, 0.518245898767047, 0.138076553592572, 0.574192448254701, 
0.133435431355833, 0.554892304454577, 0.139052739728505, 0.57825192607885, 
0.150916617717648, 0.627587957223443, 0.144179084276974, 0.599569870728368, 
0.112252179138183, 0.466801581327609, 0.109674033567054, 0.456080342428412, 
0.111055456891102, 0.461825002328107, 0.120224868167075, 0.499956072177523, 
0.125299916066184, 0.521060699301965, 0.0855819441772642, 0.355893196744622, 
0.0495125747278424, 0.205898436502569, 0.030746318019459, 0.12785880845856, 
0.0284200221496644, 0.118184888549004, 0.111823385630219, 0.465018440108279, 
0.109918488465996, 0.457096910073382, 0.11417253918809, 0.474787413895822, 
0.113843419896702, 0.473418768700291, 0.097003856181354, 0.403391308818959, 
0.0628228996117884, 0.261249528583923, 0.0389240209844475, 0.161865851395205, 
0.0297564629438263, 0.123742488239764, 0.0276489857179591, 0.114978527404441
), package = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("Baseline", 
"HSS", "VMW+ HSS"), class = "factor"), run_nb = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-54L))
```

Comment: So you want two lines of each color? Or how do you want to distinguish between run_nb and package on the plot? There are only two distinct values of `run_nb` so if you use that as `group=` you will only get two lines (one per group)

Comment: Maybe rather than `group=run_nb` you'd like something like `linetype = factor(run_nb)` so you can tell them apart.

Comment: try `group = interaction(run_nb, package)` or use `linetype`

Comment: You could also make a unique id for your groups by pasting `package` and `run_nb` together and then using it to determine line color, e.g., `dta %>% mutate(id = paste(package, run_nb, sep = "-")) %>% ggplot(aes(x = year, y = severef, color = id)) + geom_line()`.

Comment: The run_nb could range between 2 and 100 (I used only two here to limit the size of the dput) so using linetype is not really an option. Beside, I am not interested in making the distinction between run_nb.

Comment: @RichardTelford `group = interaction(run_nb, package)` do what I want. Can you make it an answer? Maybe would be also worth explaining why they don't need to use it in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16874501/overlapping-lines-in-ggplot2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that the `group` aesthetic overrides the usual behaviour of the `colour` aesthetic, which would make one line per colour. Using the `linetype` aesthetic instead of `group` would work well for a small number of groups.

With a large number of groups, you can use `interaction` to make unique run_nb/package combinations and use this as your grouping variable. Now each line has a unique grouping variable.

```r
library(ggplot2)

dta <- structure(list(year = c(2016, 2016, 2017, 2017, 2018, 2018, 2019, 2019, 2020, 2020, 2021, 2021, 2022, 2022, 2023, 2023, 2024, 2024, 2016, 2016, 2017, 2017, 2018, 2018, 2019, 2019, 2020, 2020, 2021, 2021, 2022, 2022, 2023, 2023, 2024, 2024, 2016, 2016, 2017, 2017, 2018, 2018, 2019, 2019, 2020, 2020, 2021, 2021, 2022, 2022, 2023, 2023, 2024, 2024), severef = c(0.111823385630219, 0.465018440108279, 0.109918488465996, 0.457096910073382, 0.11417253918809, 0.474787413895822, 0.124623038552219, 0.518245898767047, 0.138076553592572, 0.574192448254701, 0.133435431355833, 0.554892304454577, 0.139052739728505, 0.57825192607885, 0.150916617717648, 0.627587957223443, 0.144179084276974, 0.599569870728368, 0.112252179138183, 0.466801581327609, 0.109674033567054, 0.456080342428412, 0.111055456891102, 0.461825002328107, 0.120224868167075, 0.499956072177523, 0.125299916066184, 0.521060699301965, 0.0855819441772642, 0.355893196744622, 
 0.0495125747278424, 0.205898436502569, 0.030746318019459, 0.12785880845856, 0.0284200221496644, 0.118184888549004, 0.111823385630219, 0.465018440108279, 0.109918488465996, 0.457096910073382, 0.11417253918809, 0.474787413895822, 0.113843419896702, 0.473418768700291, 0.097003856181354, 0.403391308818959, 0.0628228996117884, 0.261249528583923, 0.0389240209844475, 0.161865851395205, 0.0297564629438263, 0.123742488239764, 0.0276489857179591, 0.114978527404441 ), package = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("Baseline", "HSS", "VMW+ HSS"), class = "factor"), run_nb = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -54L))

ggplot(dta, aes(x = year, y = severef, color = package, 
                group = interaction(run_nb, package))) +
 geom_line()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-01-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Your problem differs from [Overlapping Lines in ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16874501/overlapping-lines-in-ggplot2) as the grouping variable in that example is already unique - one per line.